# Problema al redireccionar la barra / slash al final (/) .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirección, mod-rewrite

Las url de las categorias de productos acaban en `/`
Pero los propios productos no, por lo que al añadir esta regla:

```
# si no existe un archivo que coincida con la solicitud...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# y si no termina con una barra, redireccionar a la misma dirección pero con la barra
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]$) $1/ [R,QSA,L]
```

me funciona para las categorias, pero me da error 404 con el resto de las URLs.

Es decir

- `https://www.dominio.com/coches` redirecciona a
- `https://www.dominio.com/coches/`  (perfecto)

Pero las otras URLs, como por ejemplo:

- `https://www.dominio.com/producto/ford-fiesta-5p-rojo` redirecciona a
- `https://www.dominio.com/producto/ford-fiesta-5p-rojo/`  (**error 404**)

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

He visto que hay un directorio `/producto/` en este tipo de url y quizás se podría hacer un if o algo.. De todas maneras no puedo asegurar que todos los tipos de url que dan este problema tengan ese directorio producto u otro.

Mi .htaccess es este:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex imagen.php index.php index.html index.htm 

# Forzar para que funcione con el https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dominio.com/$1 [R,L]

# Forzar que no trabaje en .es y lo convierta todo a .com . Lo tuve que asteriscar una vez con Tomas.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dominio\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dominio.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

#Nacho 07/07/2017
#Forzar que se redireccionen las url con www y se haga un 301 cuando se acceda sin www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.dominio.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio.com/$1 [R=301,L]



#08/09/2017 NACHO
Redirect 301 https://www.dominio.com/imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=10  https://www.dominio.com/estanteria-convencional.html
Redirect 301 https://www.dominio.com/imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=17  https://www.dominio.com/estanterias-ligeras.html
#08/09/2017



# GENERICAS
RewriteRule ^registro.html$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_registro [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^registro/$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_registro [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^empresa/(.*)$ /imagen.php?id_pagina=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^noticias/(.*)$ /imagen.php?id_categoria=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contactar/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_contactar [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^aviso-legal/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_aviso_legal [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^condiciones-de-compra/(.*)$ /imagen.php?id_pagina=40 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^politica-de-privacidad/(.*)$ /imagen.php?id_pagina=41 [QSA,L]


# Suyas propias

#PRODUCTOS
RewriteRule ^productos/(.*)$ /imagen.php?id_categoria_productos=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^producto/(.*)$ /imagen.php?slug_producto=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^usadas/(.*)$ /tienda/?pagina_noticias=1&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xTipo=2&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xProducto=&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xProducto_n2=&SYSTEM__pId_marca_xMarca= [QSA,L]

#Nacho 01/03/2017
RewriteRule ^transpaletas/(.*)$ /tienda/?pagina_noticias=1&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xTipo=1&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xProducto=55&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xProducto_n2=&SYSTEM__pId_marca_xMarca=&id_categoria_productos=7&pId_categoria_xTipo=1&pId_categoria_xProducto=55&pId_marca_xMarca= [QSA,L]


#Nacho
#Redirect 301 /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=25 https://www.dominio.com/carretillas/
#RewriteRule ^comprar-transpaletas/(.*)$ /tienda/?id_categoria_productos=7&pagina_noticias=1&pId_categoria_xTipo=1&pId_categoria_xProducto=55&pId_marca_xMarca=&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xTipo=1&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xProducto=55&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xProducto_n2=&SYSTEM__pId_marca_xMarca= [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^carretillas-todoterreno/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^barredoras/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fregadoras/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^recambios/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^estanterias/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=8 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^maquinas-construccion/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=19 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^maquinas-portuarias/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=20 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^carretillas/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=25 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mb-forklift/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=27 [QSA,L]

#08/09/2017
RewriteRule ^estanterias-ligeras.html(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=17 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^estanteria-convencional.html(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_dominio_verGama&pCodigo=10 [QSA,L]
#FIN 08/09/2017

#RewriteRule ^comprar-transpaletas/(.*)$ /imagen.php?id_categoria_productos=7&pagina_noticias=1&pId_categoria_xTipo=1&pId_categoria_xProducto=55&pId_marca_xMarca=&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xTipo=1&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xProducto=55&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xProducto_n2=&SYSTEM__pId_marca_xMarca= [QSA,L]
#FIN Nacho



RewriteRule ^tienda/(.*)$ /imagen.php?id_categoria_productos=7&SYSTEM__pId_categoria_xTipo=1 [QSA,L]

#CARRITO
RewriteRule ^carrito/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_tiendaWeb&pAccion=CARRITO [QSA,L]

#NOTICIAS
RewriteRule ^noticia/(.*)$ /imagen.php?slug_noticia=$1 [QSA,L]

#PAGINAS
RewriteRule ^pagina/(.*)$ /imagen.php?slug_pagina=$1 [QSA,L]

#PAGINAS
RewriteRule ^categoria-noticia/(.*)$ /imagen.php?slug_categoria=$1 [QSA,L]

# Redireccion pagina de error
RewriteRule ^error404/(.*)$ /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_gescit_error404 [QSA,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /imagen.php?clave=wsgw_gescit_error404


## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 dat"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 day"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: El cambio que hiciste el `07/07/2017`, no debería apuntar al http**S**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error no te lo está dando ni el .htaccess, ni Apache. Lo estás generando directamente en `imagen.php`.

En ese script, estás recibiendo el parámetro
`$_GET['slug_producto'] == 'ford-fiesta-5p-rojo/'`
El problema es que luego estás buscando en la base si existe ese slug, con la barra al final.

Se puede evitar que el PHP reciba esa barra al final, reemplazando la línea:

```python
RewriteRule ^producto/(.*)$ /imagen.php?slug_producto=$1 [QSA,L]
```

por

```python
RewriteRule ^producto/([^/]*)/?$ imagen.php?slug_producto=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

... y lo mismo para el resto de las URLs que no te funcionen porque tu script espera un slug sin la barra al final.

De esta forma, redireccionaría una URL como `/producto/bla` a `/producto/bla/`, y en tu script recibirías el parámetro con el valor `bla` (sin la barra al final).

Comment: Muchas gracias, parece que funciona